# List insertion, disjoint n parallel?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have been searching concurrent linked list implementations/academic papers that allow for concurrent insertions to disjoint places in the list. I would prefer a lock based approach.

Unfortunately, all the implementations I've checked out so far use list based locking as opposed to something akin to node based locking.

Any help people?

EDIT 1: Thanks all for the initial responses. Using node based locking means that for insertion after a node or deleting a node I need to lock the previous and the next node. Now it is entirely possible that by the time Thread 1 tries to lock the previous node it got deleted in Thread 2. How to guard against such accidents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not able to recommend any libraries that do this for C specifically, but if you end up doing it yourself you could potentially avoid having to have thousands of locks by re-using a small number of locks and some "hashing" to decide which to use for each node. You'd get quite a number of cases where there wouldn't be any contention if the number of locks is suitably larger than the number of nodes for little space overhead (and it's fixed, not per node).

**Update, for EDIT 1**

You could work around this by having a per-list multiple reader, single write lock, ([rwlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock)), where you acquire a "read" lock prior to getting the per-node lock for inserts, but for a delete you need to get the single "write" lock. You avoid unnecessary synchronisation issues for the read/insert operations fairly easily and deleting is simple enough. (The assumption is delete is much rarer than insert though)

Comment: Thanks, and +1 from my side. I have been thinking on similar lines but I have my questions which I have now mentioned in the question (EDIT 1). Do respond.

Comment: Added my suggestion for that problem. The lock free data structures recommended by others, that are becoming more common, are quite good but really tricky to (correctly) roll your own.

Comment: You would also need to take a read lock on the per-list `rwlock` when traversing the list normally, to prevent the nodes you're looking at from being deleted out from under you.

Comment: Interesting strategy. However this will definitely slow down the usual node search process since we cannot just march through the list randomly if insertions are happening in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using a lock-free implementation.  The idea is to use an atomic test-set operation when inserting/deleting a node.

Unfortunately, there are not many widely known implementations.  You may have to roll your own.  Here is the gcc documentation about atomic operation support:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with node based locking is that you normally have to lock two nodes for each insertion.  This can be more expensive in some situations.

Worse is that you get dining philosopher alike deadlock possibilities you have to treat.

So therefore list based locking is easier and thats why you see more about these.

If the performance characteristics of list based locking is not favorable to your application consider changing to a different data structure than as single linked list.

Comment: For singly-linked list you can avoid the deadlock surely? The new node doesn't need to be locked because no one else can know it exists yet and only one node needs to have its "next" pointer adjusted to make it work.

Comment: I don't think dining philosophers is a worry, because the list is nicely ordered and not circular.

Comment: @awoodland: the Q didn't mentioned if the list was singly linked and @Eric neither did it mention it wasn't circular.  And surely you can avoid deadlock but you have to be careful and thats all I was saying.